# sqlite select with conditions: search only if the first condition is empty

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to search in a table and if the first option doesn´t exits search the other option. Example if I can´t find with `aplication= 'app1' AND context='context1'` search with `aplication= 'app1' AND context='context2'` or else  `aplication= 'app2' AND context='context3'`

I wrote this

```
SELECT aplication AS Application, 
action AS Action 
FROM Mapper 
WHERE recognizer =  'recog1' AND event = 'event1' 
AND user = 1 AND ((aplication= 'app1' AND context='context1') 
                        || (aplication= 'app1' AND context='context2') 
                        || (aplication= 'app2' AND context='context3'))
```

but it´s not exactly what I want,for example I get this :

```
"app1"  "context2"  
"app2"  "context3"  
"app1"  "context1"
```

when I just want

```
"app1"  "context1"
```

Can I change the query?

Comment: Post (add to your question) some data that would produce the result you want.

Comment: `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL. You appear to be treating it like it means `OR`.  Read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html for details of SQL expressions.